# How to checkdb automatically in AWS RDS?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, aws, dbcc-checkdb

I'm pretty new to Amazon AWS and RDS. I have migrated my SQL Database to RDS and I have it up and running. I'm now looking to automate maintenance tasks. Anyone with experience with RDS can help me out how to configure automatic DBCC CHECKDB ? And also if its possible to configure some kind of notification in case it finds any data problem/corruptions? I know RDS has some limitations and not sure if this is possible.

As always any guidance and/or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Carlos

Comment: Try checking the [documentation first](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.Agent.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you refers to SQL Server, use the SQL Server Agent as you do usually.

Take a look here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.Agent.html

Comment: Hello, thanks. I was able to create the SQL Server Agent Job, but it seems RDS does not support notifications. =/ Any way around this?

Comment: strange, have you configured database mail?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.DBMail.html